# Program does not contain a static 'main' method suitable for an entry point async await

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have problem, I wrote simple code using async await but the compiler detected the error, i found resolve problem in stackoverflow to change the lang version My project soluction looks that:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
<LangVersion>7.2</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

But error still was.
Then I change language c# version in project build to 7.2 but nothing happend.

```
public сlass Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run();
    }

    private static async Task<int> AsyncDoItAsync()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Task<String> message = client.GetStringAsync("http://mdsm.microsoft.com");
        while (!message.IsCompleted)
        {
            DoWhenChechink();
        }
        string url = await message;
        return url.Length;
    }
    public static void DoWhenChechink()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting");
        Thread.Sleep(75);
    }
    private static async void Run() {
        int a = await AsyncDoItAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code neither shows a `static async Task Main()` nor a `static void Main()`! You only have a **non-static** `Main` and a `static async void Run`. Simply declare your `Main` as `static` or rename your `Run` method to `Main` if this was the method you intended to use as `Main`

Comment: use `await Run();` and fix the initial errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Main` method must be `static`, so make it `public static void Main(string[] args)`. However, your `Run` is an `async void`, so *right now* it'll just exit immediately. Instead, your `Main` method should - if using the up-to-date compiler  - use:

```
public static Task Main(string[] args) => AsyncDoItAsync();
```

which will then know to wait (await) the completion. You could *also* have written that as:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args) => await AsyncDoItAsync();
```

but that doesn't really add anything. Likewise, there's not really any purpose in the `Run` method here; your `Main` method might as well talk to `AsyncDoItAsync()` directly.

Comment: Top level, entrypoint async support has been added. I never knew that. Have an upvote.

Comment: @spender yeah, that's a C# 7.1 feature

Comment: @spender its out in C# 7 :)